# Entity Framework code-first approach error: sequence contains more than one element , for table with foreign key

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, code-first

I am using EF with a code-first approach. I have two model classes:

```
public class Terminal
{
    public Terminal()
    {
        Softwares = new List<Software>();
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Software> Softwares { get; set; }
}
```

This `software` class has a foreign key to the `Terminal` table:

```
public class Software
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Guid TerminalId { get; set; }

    public virtual Terminal Terminal { get; set; }
}
```

Creating the migration with the command `add-migration "add foreign key "` works fine. However when I call the `update-database` command from the package manager console, I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one element
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable1 source)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.FillInForeignKeyOperations(IEnumerable1 operations, XDocument targetModel)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteOperations(String migrationId, VersionedModel targetModel, IEnumerable1 operations, IEnumerable1 systemOperations, Boolean downgrading, Boolean auto)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ApplyMigration(DbMigration migration, DbMigration lastMigration)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClassc.b__b()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.Run()
>   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
>   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String targetMigration, Boolean force)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
>   Sequence contains more than one element

I have updated the EF as well from the console

Comment: This works fine in my environment. Maybe you have other pending migrations or changes?

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that you are using `SingleOrDefault` in your seed method, same as in this thred:

[InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15021257/invalidoperationexception-sequence-contains-more-than-one-element)

Comment: I dont have any code added explicitly in the seed method. the seed method doesnt have any code, but still i face this error. i am using 6.1.3 version of EF.

Comment: Interesting. I managed to use these classes to create the exact same migration as you and update the database. Try with a blank project.

Comment: yes, i tried with the new project and it worked. but it doesn't work with existing project. not able to understand whats wrong